# Using class level like generic bounded type parameters for method's formal arguments

Tags: java, generics, method-parameters, bounded-types

I am trying to learn `generics` in `java`. I see that at class level we can specify bounded type parameters as `class Stats <T extends Number>`.

Let's say that the class has an `array` of type `T` and an `average` method to calculate the average of those `T's` and another method to check if the averages of two objects are the same or not.

However, at the method level inside the class I can't do this:
`boolean isAverageSame(Stats<T extends Number> ob)` if I want to find that averages of two objects are the same or not.

Instead I have to do:
`boolean isAverageSame(Stats<?> ob)`

Why is this the case? Is this just how the syntax was defined in `java` or I am missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by `Method level`? Is this a method _inside_ the class or another generic method _outside_ the class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want to declare a new generic parameter for the method, in which case you could use:

```
<U extends Number> boolean isAverageSame(Stats<U> ob)
```

Note that this will allow you to do something like:

```
Stats<Integer> x = ...;
Stats<Float> y = ...;
boolean z = x.isAverageSame(y);
```

Is that what you want? If you only want to be able to compare a `Stats<Integer>` with a `Stats<Integer>` (etc) then you just need:

```
boolean isAverageSame(Stats<T> ob)
```

... in other words, the method won't introduce another generic type parameter.

Comment: So, it is part of the syntax. It does look a little redundant to me. Why can't I declare <U extends Number> within the argument itself?      Edit: - Yes, I want the method to work for all objects which are sub-type of Number.

Comment: @JakeFoster: Well one part of the method is declaring the type parameter, another is declaring the type *of* the parameter. There are cases where those won't be the same. For example, suppose you wanted to declare a type parameter with `T extends Number`, and a `List` with a type argument of `? extends T`. Or you might want to use the type parameter in two different parameters, which would also be awkward - where would you put the constraints? Separating the two out makes sense to me.

Comment: Another follow up question, would it make more sense to use bounded wildcard and have the method as `boolean isAverageSame(Stats<? extends Number> ob)`? What's the difference between the answer and the method I just mentioned?

Comment: @JakeFoster: Yes, that would be fine, if you don't need to refer to the type within the method.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm not OP but I am still curious as to why  the instance method `boolean isAverageSame(Stats<T extends Number> ob)` is invalid?

Comment: @linuxNoob: Constraints are expressed where the generic type parameter is introduced - not where they're used.

Comment: @JonSkeet - In `boolean isAverageSame(Stats<? extends Number> ob)` isn't `Stats<? extends Number>` expressing a constraint?

Comment: @linuxNoob: Yes, but at the place where the sort of anonymous type parameter is being declared... Not on a type parameter that already exists.